# Android opening Google Drive urls in Drive app or Chrome, instead of the WebView in my app

Tags: android, google-chrome, authentication, webview, google-drive-picker

My Android app has a WebView in its main layout.

This WebView is intended to open gdrive folders after letting the user login.

All this has to happen in the WebView, but I see that the system opens the urls I feed the WebView with in the Gdrive app or in the Chrome browser.
The url has the form "https://drive.google.com/open?id=...". webView.loadUrl() method is used, no intent involved.

I need to avoid this behaviour. Changing the Drive app settings in Android was not useful.

I mean, is it the WebView in my app not enough independent so to decide what to do?

Comment: Use deep-linking for this purpose. You can use https://branch.io/ for linking from web too.

Comment: @Abdullah Riaz I use webVIew.loadUrl(), no intent is involved.

Comment: yes I know. If you read the branch.io description and features, you can create a url which has specific parameters embedded in it, and then you can use this url in your webpage(which you open in webview). And then this url will redirect you in your specified app.

Comment: @Abdullah Riaz No, I have not a webpage, the WebView tries to open a GDrive folder.